# Apache Flink + Spring boot + Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, apache-flink

I have a Flink application that runs inside Spring Boot application.
The application fails to run as a jar in a Flink cluster.
I am able to run the application on my local windows machine(mini-cluster) as a jar.

The exception stack trace look like this:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: null
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.toJobGraph(JarHandlerUtils.java:126)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$getJobGraphAsync$6(JarRunHandler.java:142)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment$ProgramAbortException
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:53)
        at cdc.il.cdm.application.IngestionJob.execute(IngestionJob.java:61)
        at cdc.il.cdm.application.CdmApplication.run(CdmApplication.java:28)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
```

I am using Gradle and spring-boot-gradle-plugin to build the artifact. It seems that the artifact that is built does not match what Flink's runtime expects.
Does anyone has an example of a good recipe to create an artifact using Gradle ?

**EDIT** :
I have found a solution using shadow plugin - https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

The following gradle build file works for me on a Flink machine. The jar was built by the shadow plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

ext {
    javaVersion = '1.8'
    flinkVersion = '1.8.0'
    scalaBinaryVersion = '2.11'
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.7'
    log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':ingestion')
    compile project(':enrichment')
    compile project(':filter')
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-java:${flinkVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka_2.11:${flinkVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"

    compile "log4j:log4j:${log4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka_2.12', version: '1.8.0'

}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

bootJar {
    enabled false
}

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.*
//def timestamp = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')

shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    mergeServiceFiles()
    baseName = 'cdm-flink-app'
    classifier=null
    //version = timestamp
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cdc.il.cdm.application.CdmApplication'
    }
    append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
        paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories' ]
        mergeStrategy = "append"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you probably aren't defining mainClassName, as in

```
mainClassName = 'org.myorg.quickstart.StreamingJob'
```

Take a look at Flink's Gradle quickstart docs for more info: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html#gradle.